# Return 404 XMLHttpRequest when try do post to xml

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-404

I'm using JavaScript and AJAX for resolve my problem, I can't use JQuery :( and I have a problem, when i do a GET with XMLHttpRequest it returns a 200 code, when do a POST it returns a 404 I don't know what do more I need help :(.

### This is POST Method

```
  function putData(book) {
        var data = parseObjToXML(book);
        var oXML = new XMLHttpRequest();

        oXML.open("POST", "../data/books.xml", true);
        oXML.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        oXML.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (oXML.readyState < 4)
                changeAlertMsg("Cargando...");
            else if (oXML.readyState == 4 && oXML.status == 200) {
                changeAlertMsg("Cargado!");
            } else {
                changeAlertMsg("Error...");
                alert("Lo sentimos ha ocurrido un error, vuelva a intentarlo mas tarde... (Error: " + oXML.status + ")");
            }
        }
        oXML.send(data);
    }
```

#### parseObjToXML

```
function parseObjToXML(book) {
var params = getDataAll();
// ELIINA LA ULTIMA PALABRA
var lastIndex = params.lastIndexOf("</bookstore>");
params = params.substring(0, lastIndex);

params = params + '<book category="' + book.category + '">';

for (var i=0; i < book.title.length; i++)
    params = params + '<title lang="' + book.title[i].lang + '">' + book.title[i].title + '</title>';

for (var i=0; i < book.autor.length; i++)
    params = params + '<author>' + book.autor[i] + '</author>';

params = params + '<year>' + book.year + '</year>';
params = params + '<price>' + book.price + '</price>';
params = params + '</book>';
params = params + '</bookstore>';

return params;
}
```

#### Get all Data From books.xml

```
function getDataAll() {
        var oXML = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var txt = null;

        oXML.open("GET", "../data/books.xml", false);
        oXML.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (oXML.readyState == 4 && oXML.status == 200) {
                txt = oXML.responseText;
            }
        }
        oXML.send();
        return txt;
    }
```

**The file books.xml have 777 permissions**

**data var in putData(book) more exactly here `var data = parseObjToXML(book);` the value is that:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

```
<book category="COOKING">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>James Linn</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <title lang="es">Aprende XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
</book>
<book category="Social">
    <title lang="es">¿El hater nace o se hace?</title>
    <author>Javi Ruiz</author>
    <year>2016</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
</book>
<book category="asd"><title lang="asd">asd</title><author>asd</author><year>asd</year><price>asd</price></book></bookstore>"
```

If you need more information please let me know :)

Comment: that's not how you send a file to the server

Comment: I do not understand you, what do you mean? :(

Comment: What is the reason for choosing `POST`? Do you want to upload the file?

Comment: No, I have on another folder and a file called books.xml and I want to edit this xml adding more books. The final aim is to make a CRUD :)

Comment: This link may help. https://forums.asp.net/t/1998672.aspx?taek+that+data+and+write+it+to+a+file+text+file+or+xml+file+using+wcf

Comment: so `"../data/books.xml"` exists, and can process the POST request?

Comment: `I want to edit this xml` - you can't edit a file by `POST`ing to it - that's not how the internet works